# Why office 365 login Cache shows null value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, office365

Hi,

I am working on office 365 login for access the calendar, i have added the services to my project,it work fine without any problem, i have cleared my database and again run the project i could not get the calendar event ,It is not accessible because Cache shows null value,Again i have added the services but still it show null value for Cache,Can you please any one help me to resolve this problem,I am giving my code below.

```
        UserTokenCache Cache;

        // constructor
        public ADALTokenCache(string user)
        {
            // associate the cache to the current user of the web app
            User = user;
            this.AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeWrite = BeforeWriteNotification;


            // look up the entry in the DB
            Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == User);
            // place the entry in memory
            this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : Cache.cacheBits);
        } 



      AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {

                            var code = context.Code;

                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.ClientSecret);
                            String UserObjectId = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.Authority, new ADALTokenCache(UserObjectId));

                            authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, SettingsHelper.AADGraphResourceId);

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
```

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

> i have cleared my database and again run the project i could not get the calendar event

In this case, you need to log out and log in again so that the new cache will be stored in the database.

If this does not work, you can also run my [AspNetMvc-with-O365 project](https://github.com/dream-365/OfficeDev-Samples/releases/download/1.0/AspNetMvc-with-O365.zip) on GitHub to troubleshoot this issue.

Step#1 Download the sample project [AspNetMvc-with-O365.zip](https://github.com/dream-365/OfficeDev-Samples/releases/download/1.0/AspNetMvc-with-O365.zip).

Step#2 Register an app under Office 365 tenant AD (skip if you have an app registered), declare the Office 365 Exchange Online > Read user mail permission and set the REPLY URL as "http://localhost:2659/".
[image]

Step#3 In the web.config file, copy the ClientId, TenantId and Client Secret from Azure AD portal.

[image]

Step#4 Run the project in Visual Studio and log in with Azure AD account

The expected result should be as following:

[image]

You can also click the "Clear the cache database" button if you have acquire token issues.